# How can I open multiple links using a hotkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hotkeys

I want to open multiple links using a hotkey on a web page. For this I am using `accesskey` for hotkey mapping and the following code.

```
<a href="https://link1"
   onclick="window.open('link2'); window.open('link3'); return true;"
   accesskey="1">Some text</a>
```

The `onclick` event will not acknowledge when the element is accessed using `accesskey` (but tab to select and enter works). Is there another DOM event, or method which can accomplish the function of hotkey = 'open_multiple_windows'?

I have tried to use `onsubmit`, `onchange`, `oninput`, `onselect` and `onopen`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://google.com','_blank'); window.open('https://bing.com','_blank');" accesskey=1></a>
```

This code should work BUT multiple pages could be blocked (as a popup)

Comment: I'm happy to hear that. If you want, you could mark this answer as the correct one :)

Comment: Just figured out how to do that, I'm on the up and up :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

since you are using jQuery this can be achieved by capturing the key down or key up and trigger open in different tab or window,

```
$(document).keydown(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank');
  }
});
```

This would open up stackoverflow into a new window when the user press on the ENTER key.

Comment: OP wants to achieve this on press of a key, not on click.

Comment: changed it to keydown, but you can use keyup or even keypress, they work the same way.